Completness preserved by diffeomorphism?
Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ a local diffeomorphism of a manifold $M$ into a Riemannian manifold $N$. Introduce on $M$ a  metric such that $f$ is a local isometry( how? I think this is related to covering maps).  Could you provide an explicit example that disproves the statement
$$N\text { is complete}\implies M\text { is complete}$$
In  Do Carmo's book Riemannian Geometry , if there exists a $c > 0$ such that $$|v| \geq c |df_p(v)|\;\forall p \in M,\;\forall v \in T_p M$$ the statement is true.

Hint: if $N$ is connected then the pull-back of a complete metric via a local diffeomorphism $f: M\to N$ is complete if and only if $f$ is a covering map. If you want a trivial example, take the inclusion map of an interval to the real line.
